# Java Coding Style & Emacs cc-mode configuration

Tags: java, emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, cc-mode

I'm using GNU/Emacs HEAD with the included cc-mode (c-version 5.32.2) on a GNU/Linux Debian machine.

I'm trying to define a custom style to manage the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), [Android's Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) and some custom rules.

As a lisp beginner, it does not seem wise to start from scratch. As a consequence, I used [google-c-style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-c-style.el) as a starting point and I managed to get the intended behavior for the most indenting rules, with an exception on nested condition (see the code snippet below).

From [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365612/how-to-i-configure-emacs-in-java-mode-so-that-it-doesnt-automatically-align-met), I have defined `(arglist-cont-nonempty . ++)` in my custom style (full code: [custom-java-style.el](https://github.com/nibua-r/custom-java-style/blob/master/custom-java-style.el)). Unfortunately, although most cases is indented as intended:

```
if ((condition1 && condition2)
        || (condition3 && condition4)
        ||!(condition5 && condition6)) {
    doSomethingAboutIt();

    someMethod(longExpression1, longExpression2, longExpression3,
            longExpression4, longExpression5);
}
```

Nested condition are wrongly indented:

```
if (!(deviceRegistred.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceAdress)
                && deviceRegistred.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceName))) {
    doSomethingAboutIt();
}
```

<kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> report `Syntactic analysis: ((arglist-cont-nonempty 2447 2450) (arglist-cont-nonempty 2447 2452))` on the second line and I obviously have a 16 spaces (2 times `++`) indentation instead of 8 (`++`).

I'd like to get the following indentation:

```
if (!(deviceRegistred.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceAdress)
        && deviceRegistred.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceName))) {
    doSomethingAboutIt();
}
```

I tried to define a `(,(when (fboundp …)))` condition like the one used for `statement-cont` but without success (my lack of lisp knowledge don't help either).

Now, the question: Is my approach right or wrong? How could/should I implement the intended behavior (i.e. detect when i'm in a nested condition to get the right indentation)?

(I don't want to use malabar-mode or JDEE, so please don't tell me to use them.)

Cheers,

Renaud

**Update 2011/12/06 (reacting to the comments)**

We wouldn't begin a holy war here. Those who want to use Emacs, for their own reasons, can stick to Emacs, the others will do as they want…

Saying that, I work within a team in which I'm the only one to use Emacs, the others are fond of Eclipse. Since I'm in charge of the coding rules, I have worked with my colleagues to get the right save actions and help to configure the Eclipse's formatter. All I could say is that: the Eclipse save actions and formatter are not easy to configure at all… The main difference is that you have a nice GUI with nice checkboxes but it doesn't help much to reduce the complexity.

I stick with Emacs…

Comment: I would use an IDE specifically designed to develop, debug and test Java applications.  Its not as general purpose as emacs, but is likely to support Java specific features much better.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The question here is not whether I should/would/could use Eclipse or another full-fledged java-aware IDE but how to solve a very specific indenting issue within emacs… Anyway, thanks for your comment!

Comment: certainly a comment and not an answer to your problem. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Emacs has allowed custom indentation in C for decades now, and given that Java and C have strictly the same syntax for `if` condition (that's the matter of the question, right?), and I don't see how other IDE should do a better job here.

Comment: @Antoine, A Java IDE wouldn't help, but a good lisp IDE might.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't think anything can come close to Emacs for that matter ;)

Comment: I guess that makes Emacs the best Lisp IDE.  It really should have an easy to configure code style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say, that Emacs does the right thing.
Consider this case:

```
if (!(deviceRegistred.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceAdress)
                && deviceRegistred.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceName))
        || otherCondition) {
    doSomethingAboutIt();
}
```

If nested condition was indented 8 chars that would be a confusing variant:

```
if (!(deviceRegistred.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceAdress)
        && deviceRegistred.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceName))
        || otherCondition) {
    doSomethingAboutIt();
}
```